# Calculator using switch and functions in C

Tags: c, function, switch-statement, calculator

This is our exercise today and our first time coding call functions in class. These are the instructions given to us:

1. I have to make a C Program calculator with choices: 0 - exit, 1 - add, 2 - subtract, 3 - multiply and 4 - divide.
2. Once the user inputs their choice, I ask for two numbers from them.
3. I need to use functions for each arithmetic operation.
4. When I'm done with calculating, it should go back to the menu.
5. The program only ends when the user chooses 0.

This my program that I've edited a lot already.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
int mul(int, int);
int div(int, int);

int main(){
int num1, num2, choice;

printf("[0] Exit\v[1] Add\v[2] Subtract\v[3] Multiply\v[4] Divide");
scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice){
    case 0:
        return 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d", add(num1,num2));
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d ", sub(num1,num2));
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d", mul(num1,num2));
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d", div(num1,num2));
        break;
    default:
        printf("That is not a valid choice.");
        break;
}
    //Addition
int add(int x,int y){
    int z = x + y;
    return z;
}   
//Subtraction
int sub(int a,int b){
    int c = a - b;
    return  c;
}   
//Multiplication
int mul(int d,int e){
    int f = d * e;
    return f;
    }
//Division
int div(int g,int h){
    int i = g / h;
    return i;
}
}
```

For now, it's down to two errors only:
[Error] conflicting types for 'div'
and
previous declaration of 'div' was here

Comment: This obviously won't compile. So obviously it needs to be improved. If you don't understand what one of the compiler messages is for and why your code is wrong then ask that question. Otherwise get the code to compile and then run it and see if it works (it won't ... but you might have a better idea of why).

Comment: I've already edited it, but I always get this error: [Error] conflicting types for 'div'

Comment: There's no need for those add etc. functions ... just use the operators directly. And don't repeat the printf's and scanf's to get the numbers ... do them before the switch, or put them into a function.

Comment: In C you cannot define one function in another one

Comment: Beginners can get help from here -> [Program to create calculator using functions](http://www.codeforwin.in/2015/06/c-program-to-create-simple-calculator-using-switch-case.html)

Answer (score 1):

"I've already edited it, but I always get this error: [Error] conflicting types for 'div' "

=> because the function name div() already defined in stdlib.h.

You should rename it by another name.

e.g: Divide(int, int);

Comment: or get rid of stdlib: what function do you call from stdlib such that you need to have it in your code?

Comment: Better: just use `/` and get rid of the function; there's no need for it.

Comment: @Jim: Using *functions* rather than operands, the entire switch construction can easily be removed in lieu of an array of pointers to functions, which will (a) be expandable, (b) avoid lots of shared code, and (c) might be in the next lesson.

Comment: The array has no advantage over the switch, which is also expandable and doesn't require duplicated code.

Answer (score 1):

One basic principle of programming is D.R.Y. = Don't Repeat Yourself. If you see the same code repeated in the same way in multiple spots then it means that you could group it in a nice function. You could save some space by not allocating a variable in each math function, simply return the math formula.

Also, if this is meant to be a continuous cycle, you should probably use a loop such

```
while(true) {
...
}
```

and exit if the user types 0

Answer (score 0):

You've got a *huge* problem by coding:

int sum = add; // *etc*

this doesn't make any sense -- you're assigning a function pointer (`add`) to an `int` (`sum`)

You simply want (later on in the code):

```
printf("%d\n", add(num1, num2);
```

you are making the code *far* too complex -- simplicity is *good*!.

Comment: I just realized that too. I've edited my code now, but it still has errors.

Comment: That's *exactly* why you want to KISS (keep it simple silly) so you can focus on the *real* problems.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you have a syntax error. Your function `main()` looks like:

```
int main(void) {
   ...whatever...
   switch (choice) {
     ...whatever...
   }

int add() {
         ...
}

...whatever...

} /* wrong place for closing '}' (this closes the "main() {" block */
```

The result of your code is that the functions add(), sub(), etc., are defined inside the body of `main()`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You function declaration should be outside the main function. So close the main function, than define add, sub, mul, div. It will resolve the errors.
Use looping to do some process again and again.
To avoid code redundancy, you can create a function that gets the input values and store it in memory address. Call this function wherever you want instead of repeating codes.

Below you can find a function name **getData** which gets two values from user and stores it in the memory address passed to that function. The calling program will pass the memory address where those values has to be stored.

Some Guidelines while writing code:

```
1.) Write DRY(Dont Repeat Yourself) type code.
2.) Use only required header files. stdio.h is enough to do basic programming in your case.
```

Simple Working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

// Function Prototype
int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
int mul(int, int);
int div(int, int);
void getData(int *, int *);

// Main Function
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, choice;
    while(1)
    {
      printf("\n[0] Exit\n[1] Add\n[2] Subtract\n[3] Multiply\n[4] Divide\nEnter Your Choice:");
      scanf("%d", &choice);
      switch(choice)
      {
         case 0:
           return 0;
         case 1:
           getData(&num1, &num2); // get Input Values
           printf("%d", add(num1,num2));
           break;
         case 2:
           getData(&num1, &num2); // get Input Values       
           printf("%d ", sub(num1,num2));
           break;
         case 3:
           getData(&num1, &num2); // get Input Values       
           printf("%d", mul(num1,num2));
           break;
         case 4:
           getData(&num1, &num2); // get Input Values
           printf("%d", div(num1,num2));
           break;
         default:
           printf("That is not a valid choice.");
           break;
      }
    }
}

// Get Memory Address of num1, num2 and store input values in those locations.
void getData(int *num1_ptr, int *num2_ptr)
{
printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
    scanf("%d", num1_ptr);
printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
    scanf("%d", num2_ptr);
}

//Addition
int add(int x,int y)
{   return x+y;   }   

//Subtraction
int sub(int x,int y)
{   return  x-y;  }   

//Multiplication
int mul(int x,int y)
{   return x*y;   }

//Division
int div(int x,int y)
{   return x/y;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
int mul(int, int);
float dib(float, float);

int main(){
int num1, num2, choice;

printf("1:addiction\n2:substraction\n3:multiplication\n4:division\n0:exit\nplease enter your choice:");
scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice){
    case 0:
        return 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d", add(num1,num2));
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d ", sub(num1,num2));
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d", mul(num1,num2));
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%f", dib(num1,num2));
        break;
    default:
        printf("That is not a valid choice.");
        break;
}
        }

    //Addition
int add(int x,int y){
    int z = x + y;
    return z;
}
//Subtraction
int sub(int a,int b){
    int c = a - b;
    return  c;
}
//Multiplication
int mul(int d,int e){
    int f = d * e;
    return f;
    }
//Division
float dib(float g,float h){
    float i = g / h;
    return i;
}
```